# Conversion of text to vector in python

Tags: python, tokenize

```
import tokenize
tags = [
  "python, tools",
  "linux, tools, ubuntu",
  "distributed systems, linux, networking, tools",
]
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vec = CountVectorizer(tokenizer=tokenize)
data = vec.fit_transform(tags).toarray()
print data
```

I am trying to convert text to vector. But I am facing the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 398, in fit_transform
term_count_current = Counter(analyze(doc))
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 313, in <lambda>
tokenize(preprocess(self.decode(doc))), stop_words)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I have tried to import other libraries too. But nothing seems to be working. How can I correct it?

Comment: You probably want `from tokenize import tokenize`

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Not quite familiar with this approach, but will `tokenize` work for the data set given? The [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tokenize.html#tokenize.tokenize) say about tokenize : *The first parameter, readline, must be a callable object which provides the same interface as the readline() method of built-in file objects* Will it work with a list of strings? Idk if you need that `tokenizer` setting in the first place?

Comment: It should work without an explicit tokenizer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly a solution more of a work around from the main page of nltk.org:

```
>>> import nltk
 >>> sentence = """At eight o'clock on Thursday morning
 ... Arthur didn't feel very good."""
>>> tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
>>> tokens
['At', 'eight', "o'clock", 'on', 'Thursday', 'morning',
'Arthur', 'did', "n't", 'feel', 'very', 'good', '.']
```

Hope this helps

Comment: **What I need is the vector representation of the input text**

Comment: There is a tutorial on this webpage, let me know if you are not able to get it to work- http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html

Comment: @Neenu if you found the answer useful, kindly upvote or accept the answer.